# Resize a dynamic table in another workbook

Tags: excel, vba, excel-tables, listobject

I have a macro enabled workbook that scrapes data together and puts it nicely formatted into a plain workbook. This helps with security issues for users who can't run macros.

I made an example:

```vb
Sub Test()
Dim appExcel As Excel.Application
Dim wDatabase As Workbook
Dim ob As ListObject
Set appExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

'DOESN'T WORK when run from another workbook
Set wDatabase = appExcel.Workbooks.Open("C:\Test\Book1.xlsx")

'WORKS when macro run in the book with the table (and above line commented out)
'Set wDatabase = ActiveWorkbook

Set ob = wDatabase.Sheets("Sheet1").ListObjects("Table1")
ob.Resize Range("$B$3:$D$13")

'Save changes
wDatabase.Save
wDatabase.Close

End Sub
```

Two workbooks: Book1.xlsx and Book2.xlsm
Book1.xlsx has a table ("Table1") on "Sheet1" in cells B3 to D14. I want to make it B3 to D13.

If I run the macro with that worksheet active (as shown with the commented out code) it works.

When I try from another workbook, it fails.

Sometimes it will say:

> Run-time error '1004': This action won't work on multiple selections.

Other times Excel enters a corrupt mode and says

> Run-time error '-2147023170 (800706be0)'; Automation error. The
> remote procedure call failed.

The range should resize.

---

Changing this worked.

```
Set wDatabase = Workbooks.Open("C:\Test\Book1.xlsx")
```

Comment: `Range("$B$3:$D$13")` is not qualified. Qualify it with the sheet you want to use.

Comment: Why are you creating a new instance of Excel?  You could  just do `Set wDatabase = Workbooks.Open("C:\Test\Book1.xlsx")`

Comment: These new instances are accumulating since you aren't quitting any of them whether there is an error or not. You need to use an error-handling routine that will, in case of an error, redirect the flow to lines that will close the workbook and quit the instance e.g. `If Not wDataBase Is Nothing Then wDatabase.Close False` and `If Not appExcel Is Nothing Then appExcel.Quit`.

Comment: If you want to stick with the hard-coded address you could do `ob.Resize ob.Range.Worksheet.Range("B3:D13")`. But I would rather shrink the size by one row, e.g. `With ob.Range: ob.Resize .Resize(.Rows.Count - 1): End With` or `With ob: .Resize .Range.Resize(.Range.Rows.Count - 1): End With`.

Comment: chris neilsen nailed it. I thought that was a required step before opening a different workbook.

Answer (score 0):

### Resize a Table Using Another Instance of Excel (Error Handling)

```vb
Sub Test()
    Dim IsSuccess As Boolean
    On Error GoTo ClearError ' start error-handling routine...
    
    Dim xlApp As Excel.Application: Set xlApp = New Excel.Application
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("C:\Test\Book1.xlsx")
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = wb.Sheets("Sheet1")
    Dim lo As ListObject: Set lo = ws.ListObjects("Table1")
    
    ' If you want to see how it works when an error occurs,
    ' uncomment the Err.Raise line.
    ' Create a breakpoint and in the Task Manager locate the new instance
    ' under Background Processes. If you don't use 'Quit', it will remain
    ' open after the procedure exits.
    'Err.Raise 13
    ' With 'F8', step through the rest of the code to see its flow.
    ' In the Task Manager see how the instance is gone.
    
    lo.Resize ws.Range("B3:D13") ' the header row needs to be 3
    
    IsSuccess = True
ProcExit:
    On Error Resume Next ' prevent endless loop if error in the following lines
        If Not wb Is Nothing Then wb.Close IIf(IsSuccess, True, False)
        If Not xlApp Is Nothing Then xlApp.Quit
    On Error GoTo 0
    Exit Sub
ClearError: ' ... continue error-handling routine
    Debug.Print "Run-time error '" & Err.Number & "':" & vbLf & Err.Description
    Resume ProcExit ' redirect to exit routine
End Sub
```